# Can't find Custom Error pages in sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

when i navigate to Administration » Settings » Advanced and expand Pages but i don't find the custom error page[image: here is the image]

Comment: Are you on version 12.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the web.config file in ur code and inside the   under the  tag closed add this

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error-pages/generic-error-page" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error-pages/file-not-found" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error-pages/no-access" />
</customErrors>
```

Create the pages in sitefinity pages

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the full documentation: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/administration-custom-error-pages

Additionally this feature is only avalailable in version 12.2 and higher as pointed out in the comment.